# How to add a style role column to a google charts aggregated datatable

Tags: charts, google-apps-script, google-visualization

I have a datatable created from database data that gets aggregated by google.visualization.data.group, then fed into a columnChart.

By default, the resulting chart's bars are all the same color but i would like to make the bars different colors (by iterating through the datatable and assigning a different color to each row in the datable).For now, i'll just try to assign the colour 'gold' to each bar, for simplicity.

This is the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart) for a columnChart and is the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#stylerole) for style roles.

I don't think my code can be far wrong:

```
var groupedCategoryData = new google.visualization.data.group(
        stacked01Data, // arg 1 is the array of input data
        [{ // arg 2 is the key (An array of numbers/objects being columns to group by)
            column: 0, type: 'string' 
        }], 
        [{ 'column': 1, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.avg, 'type': 'number' }]
    );//group. col 1 = score

    //*****************         
    groupedCategoryData.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'style' });
    for (var i = 0; i < groupedCategoryData.length; i++) {
        groupedCategoryData[i][2] = 'color: gold';
    }//for
    //*****************

    var stacked01_options = {
        width: 500,
        height: 300
    };//options

    var stacked01 = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('stackedChart01_div'));
    stacked01.draw(groupedCategoryData, stacked01_options);
```

The result is a chart whose bars are all default blue. I admit this is my first foray into javascript. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can use a data view over the grouped data to provide the color, similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46605079/5090771)...

Answer (score 0):

Yep, that did it. thanks WhiteHat. working code:

```
//include the bar color data
var colorsGreen = [
    [0, 1, '#6AB293'],
    [1, 2, '#449371'],
    [2, 3, '#277553'],
    [3, 4, '#115639'],
    [4, 5, '#043822']
];
groupedCategoryData.addColumn('string', 'barColor');
var groupedCategoryDataView = new google.visualization.DataView(groupedCategoryData);
groupedCategoryDataView.setColumns([0, 1, {
    calc: function (dt, row) {
        var rowValue = dt.getValue(row, 1);
        var color;
        colorsGreen.forEach(function (range, index) {
            if ((rowValue >= range[0]) && ((rowValue < range[1]) || (range[1] === null))) {
                color = range[2];
            }
        });
        return color;
    },
    role: 'style',
    type: 'string'
}]);


var stacked01_options = {
    width: 500,
    height: 300
};//options

var stacked01 = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('stackedChart01_div'));
stacked01.draw(groupedCategoryDataView, stacked01_options);
```

}